# MySQL not null in left join condition

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

My query looks like:

```sql
   SELECT * 
     FROM users U 
LEFT JOIN posts P ON P.userId = U.id AND P.userId IS NOT NULL;
```

Why the query also return result where `userId` is `null` ?

I know that for my needs I can use `INNER JOIN` to get only posts related to user but is so strange that `LEFT JOIN` support multiple conditions, but not work with NOT NULL conditions.

Comment: Put this on `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between “INNER JOIN” and “OUTER JOIN”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091641/3404097)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because "posts" does not contain the null-values and hence they can´t be filtered at that stage. The Null-values are only generated trough the join, when the server can´t find a corresponding row on the right table. So just put the not null in the where clause and it will work:

```
SELECT * FROM users U LEFT JOIN posts P ON P.userId = U.id WHERE userId IS NOT NULL;
```

(EDIT: You should use an inner join for productive work though, as it is the proper way and will give you much greater performance.)

You can also see all users who don´t have posts by inverting that:

```
SELECT * FROM users U LEFT JOIN posts P ON P.userId = U.id WHERE userId IS  NULL;
```

Comment: The first query is nothing more than an obfuscated inner join of course.

Comment: Shure, but as stated in the question, the Author already knows that inner join would be the proper way.
Maybe it helps to unsderstand the mechanics of join though, in that it creates a new "virtual" table.

Answer (score 0):

You are outer joining the `posts` table. This means for every `users` record that has no match in `posts` you still get this record with all `posts` columns null.

So say you have a `users` record with userid = 5 and there is no `posts` record with id = 5.

```
ON P.userId = U.id AND P.userId IS NOT NULL
```

The two combined conditions are not met (there is no record with userid 5), so you get the `users` record with all `posts` columns set to null in your results.

Maybe you are simply looking for an inner join? All `users` records with their `posts` data?

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users U LEFT JOIN
     posts P
     ON P.userId = U.id AND P.userId IS NOT NULL;
```

Returns all rows in the `users` as well as all columns from `posts`, regardless of whether or not they match.  This is true, regardless of whether the `ON` clause evaluates to TRUE or FALSE.

What you want is a `WHERE`.  In addition, you should only select the columns from `users`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users U LEFT JOIN
     posts P
     ON P.userId = U.id 
WHERE P.userId IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that you can also accomplish this using `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the LEFT JOIN *must* return every row from the left table by it's definition. The raw *may* be augmented with the data of the right table depending on the ON clause evaluation. So the following code must return a row.

```
select u.*, p.*
from ( 
    select 1 as id 
    ) u
left join (
    -- no data at all
    select 2 as id where 1=2
    ) p on 3 = 4 -- never is true
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
SELECT * FROM users U LEFT JOIN posts P ON P.userId = U.id
SELECT * FROM users U LEFT JOIN posts P ON P.userId = U.id where P.userId IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: And then what? He asked for an explanation, not a query.